# Extension of real functions to Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^*_+\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is locally the restriction of an holomorphic function.

Notating $R$ the Riemann surface of the complex logarithm, with coordinates $(r,\theta)$ with $r>0$ and $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, we find that the Cauchy-Riemann conditions in this system of coordinates is given by:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{ir}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}.
$$

My question is: the Cauchy-Riemann are a system of partial differential equations, if we use the function $f$ as an initial condition for $\theta=0$, are there conditions for the existence of a solution that is everywhere holomorphic on $R$? If yes, is it possible to know its form?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If a solution exists, then its real part is the harmonic function $u$ with the given initial values $u=f$, $u_\theta=0$ (and the imaginary part is the conjugate function of $u$).

The problem is that the Cauchy problem for an elliptic equation (such as $u_{xx}+u_{yy}$) is ill-posed. The solution exists if and only $f$ is given by a power series that extends analytically to the entire region. But in this case, it's the form of the power series that tells you that the solution exists, not the PDE. There is nothing in the PDE that says that the initial value problem will have a solution; rather the opposite, the PDE does its best to kill the solution.